# How to avoid the occurence of blank screen between two Activities in Android

Tags: android

I am working on the Android web base Application. In my application, I am call the web services, parse it and show the parsed data on my view. The data contain text and images. My problem is when i am moving first screen to second screen(in second screen there is a xml data which is display the images and text and it has large number of data, near about 100). But when i am clicking on move button there is a blank screen appear till that xml data is loaded on view and then display the second screen.
         I want to show the progress dialog on that screen till load all the data. So please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key word for you: `ASyncTask`

I recommend to do the XML parsing in an ASyncTask and while doing that displaying a spinner/progress bar. A tutorial can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html